# How does this Play 2 ScalaTemplates code work

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

Please explain the code below:

```
@title(text: String) = @{
  text.split(' ').map(_.capitalize).mkString(" ")
}

<h1>@title("hello world")</h1>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A breakdown of the [reusable code block](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0/ScalaTemplates) `@title(text: String)`

1. `text.split( ' ' )` separates the text into a *List* by splitting the string by **' '**, e.g. *"hello world"* would become *["hello", "world"]*
2. `map(_.capitalize)` iterates the *List*, calls `capitalize` on each element, and returns the new List, e.g. *["hello", "world"]* becomes *["Hello", "World"]*. [This blog post](http://ananthakumaran.in/2010/03/29/scala-underscore-magic.html) give a good overview of **_**.
3. `mkString(" ")` converts the *List* back to a *String* by joining the string with **" "**, e.g. *["Hello", "World"]* becomes *"Hello World"*

In summary, `@title(text: String)` capitalizes all words in a String.

The `<h1>@title("hello world")</h1>` is how you could ouput the result in a [ScalaTemplate](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0/ScalaTemplates).

Comment: Thanx a lot for the explanation....Really helpful content..Also it would be great if you can suggest some good scala template tutorial...

Comment: Unfortunately I do not know of any good tutorial. My only suggestion would be to look at the Play 2.0 samples: https://github.com/playframework/Play20/tree/master/samples/scala in combination with the template docs: http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0/ScalaTemplates